# Can you emulate the missing 'Includes' parameter for recursesubirs in Inno Setup?

Tags: regex, inno-setup

Inno Setup provides an *Excludes* parameter for *File* entries.  The *Excludes* parameter specifies a list of patterns matched against files to exclude from files encountered in a recursive search of the given directory.  I want pattern matching for files to **include** from the recursive directory search.

For example, suppose I have a directory called *MyDir* and there are *locale* directories at various levels below that and each *locale* directory contains 70 or so language directories.  (My app is a single language app so including the language files for only one language will reduce the number of files zipped into the installer package by thousands of files.)

Ideally I'd write my *Files* directive like,

```
Source: MyDir\*; Includes: locale/en; Flags: recursesubdirs
```

But, alas, there is no *Includes* parameter.  Or, if the *Excludes* parameter accepted regular expressions I could write something like,

```
Source: MyDir\*; Excludes: locale\(?!en\); Flags: recursesubdirs
```

When I could not figure out how to do this with the basic features I tried a custom *Check* function.  Unfortunately, the *Check* function is not run at the time the installer is compiled so the foreign language files get zipped into the installer and then later excluded when the install setup wizard is run.

Short of excluding all *locale* directories in the main *File* directive then declaring an "include" directive for each and every *locale/en* directory under *MyDir* is there a way to do this with Inno Setup?

Looking at this problem more generally if Inno Setup was sophisticated enough it would provide some intelligent mechanism for compiling single language installers.  However, it's foreign language awareness appears to be limited to selecting which messages are displayed when you run the install wizard during installation.

Comment: I would exclude all the language directories and make the language(s) as a separate entry. That will be even more readable and easier to maintain.

Comment: There are 15 different locale/en directories under _MyDir_.  I _could_ use 15 lines in the Inno Setup _Files_ section to define them all but this does not strike me as easy to maintain.  (It's third party software and they could add new locale directories or change the name of a parent directory in future releases then the installer would silently break the installed app.)